# How can I add an extra div using the wp menu array in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having issues with a design I have had back from the front end dev, I have created and set up a custom nav but due to the nature of the nav e.g its set in columns it requires me to add another div into the sub menu  so the standard below wont work

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 
?>
```

Is there actually a way of doing this or is it impossible as I have tried lots of code I found but nothing seems to work I have posted the HTML i have to work with below so you get an idea, any help would be appreciated

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
           <li><a href="index.html" class="active">HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="internal.html">ABOUT</a>
           <div class="sf-mega" style="display: none">
               <nav id="subNav">
                   <!-- container -->
                   <div class="container">
                   <div class="colFour menu first">
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="internal.html">Page 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="internal.html">Vision</a></li>
                   </ul>
                   </div>
                   <div class="colFour menu">
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="internal.html">Page 2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="internal.html">pag3 3</a></li>
                   </ul>
                   </div>
                   <div class="colFour menu">
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="internal.html">page 4</a></li>
                   <li><a href="internal.html">page 5</a></li>
                   </ul>
                   </div>
                   <div class="colFour menu">
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="internal.html">page 6</a></li>
                   </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <!-- /container --> 
               </nav>
           </div>
           </li>
           <li><a href="/Test 1">Test 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="/">Test 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="/">Test 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="internal.html">VACANCIES</a></li>
           <li><a href="internal.html">CONTACT</a></li>
       </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Walker_Nav_Menu class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/). It defines how a menu items are printed and gives you full control over it.

From the resource:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'   => 'Your menu',
    'walker' => new New_Walker_Nav_Menu()
) );

/**
 * Custom walker class.
 */
class New_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * Adds classes to the unordered list sub-menus.
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     */
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        // Depth-dependent classes.
        $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
        $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
        $classes = array(
            'sub-menu',
            ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
            ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
            'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
        );
        $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

        // Build HTML for output.
        $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
    }

    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * Adds main/sub-classes to the list items and links.
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     * @param int    $id     Current item ID.
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

        // Depth-dependent classes.
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
            ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
            ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );
        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

        // Passed classes.
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

        // Build HTML.
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

        // Link attributes.
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';

        // Build HTML output and pass through the proper filter.
        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```